# How to write polite deadline email?

Tags: business-writing, email

I'm trying to collect feedback from my colleagues and the deadline is on 10-April-2012, 2.00pm. So in my mail I write:

> Please email your feedback to me before 2.00pm, 10-April-2012(Tuesday).

Does it seems too commanding instead of being polite?

Comment: Is it really that hard, writing polite emails? Take a look here: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/how-to-write-a-polite-reminder-email

Comment: Yes actually, I think it is.

Answer (score 4):

If there is a tight deadline, as you seem to have, I always follow the sentence containing the deadline information with another sentence that says something like, "If you foresee a problem with replying by tomorrow, please let me know that as soon as possible."

This gives them a chance to tell you that the deadline is not feasible for them.

Answer (score 3):

> Just a reminder: I need your feedback by this Tuesday, 10 April, before 2pm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your wording is perfectly polite. It's neither demanding nor wimpy.

If you think it would help, add a few words about why you need the feedback by 2pm. Something like, "so I can revise the document before the 3pm staff meeting."  That gives people some context in which to understand the deadline.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is better: I am waiting for your feedback till 02/03/2015